# running and testing ejabberd on localhost?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia, yaws, nitrogen

I have installed ejabberd on my HP pavilion (Entertainment laptop running windows 7), during the installation i was prompted to enter the server domain. Since i wanted to experiment on it, i entered "localhost".When i try starting it, the web admin interface shows that an error has ocurred.checking the 3 log files, i cannot find the error. It seems that some ports have been blocked. But No error i find in the logs. How can i get it up and running so that i can test it on localhost using XMMP client or using jabberlang-XMPP driver.

```
Speaking of jabberlang XMPP erlang client library....
```

Can someone please show me some examples on how u have used it? Also, which parameters can i uncomment or modify in ejabberd's conf file so as to run it on localhost.Should i have specified the server domain explicitly as "127.0.0.1" instead of "locahost"  ?

```
Something on the "oneTeam XMPP client" embeddable in Firefox
```

I have got my firefox running this client and once i log in, it provides presence information on the friends i have on Gmail, not on the processOne IM free server i created [username@name.p1.im]. But i could chat with these friends of mine direct in their Gmail accounts. I need to understand how i will be able to use this if i install my own ejabberd server. Please remember to point me to resources about jabberlang XMMP client library. Thanks

/joshmuza@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jabberlang is deprecated. If you need an Erlang XMPP library, you should use exmpp.